# Directive is not called

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I need to use directive to validate a field,
My html code:

```
<mat-form-field>
            <input id="datanint" formControlName="dateBirth" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker startView="multi-year" [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>

        </mat-form-field>
```

This is my directive code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[matDatepicker]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: DateValidatorDirective, multi: true
  }]
})
export class DateValidatorDirective implements Validators {

  validator: ValidatorFn;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  console.log("INIT");
    this.validator = validateregex();
  }

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    return this.validator(c);
  }
}


const regExp = new RegExp('(>|<)+');

function validateregex(): ValidatorFn {

  return (c: AbstractControl) => {
    const isValid = regExp.test(c.value);
    console.log("Valid" + isValid);
    //let isValid = c.value === 'Rahul';
    if (isValid) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return {
        validator: {
          valid: false
        }
      };
    }

  }
}
```

And I put in the `app.module`

```
  declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ....
        DateValidatorDirective
    ],
```

The proble is that the `console.log("init")` in directive is never called so I suppose that the directive doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: how do you use it in template ??

Comment: @Harkal yes, I modify my question!

Comment: if everything is ok with your code then look for the logs in whole logs because the creation of objects happen well before the use in angular

Comment: https://scotch-io.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-custom-validator-directive-confirm-password-in-angular-2/amp

Comment: look at this the validator is extending existing validator and is forwarding reference in providers declaration

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [official document](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) carefully. I think, you have to change the class name `ValidatorDirective` to `DateValidatorDirective`.